# Django comment moderation error: AlreadyModerated at /

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add the comments framework to a weblog I'm creating in Django. Adding the comments system appears to be working fine until I attempt to enable [comment moderation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/comments/moderation/).

I add the following code to my models.py as per the instructions on the above link. My model is called Post which represents a post in the weblog.

```
class PostModerator(CommentModerator):
    email_notification = False
    enable_field = 'allow_comments'

moderator.register(Post, PostModerator)
```

If I attempt to preview the site I get error **AlreadyModerated at /** with the exception `The model 'post' is already being moderated`. I have no idea why I'm getting this error as I have only just enabled comments and am not sure why Post would already be moderated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just had a similar problem today, but I think I've solved it :)
In my case the issue was that django was loading models.py twice and therefore trying to register the model for comment moderation twice as well. I fixed this by modifying the code from:

```
moderator.register(Post, PostModerator)
```

to:

```
if Post not in moderator._registry:
    moderator.register(Post, PostModerator)
```

Comment: not fully correct solution. blog.models and mysite.blog.models - different modules, and the importer, rather than import the module one time and use it when necessary, import it twice, and this causes the error described.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that CommentModerator (the superclass for PostModerator) is moderated by default?